# Accumulating data in sorted manner in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, hash

I want to store triples of data associated with key. I have triples of this form:

```
"data1" "data2"  "data3"
```

where `data1` is an integer. I have a mechanism to triples to key. For example `"key1"` is mapped to

```
["data1", "data2", "data3"]
```

There can be multiple triples associated with a key. For example, `[4, "data2", "data3"], [1, "data5", "data6"] and [3, "data8", "data9"]` may be mapped to `"key1"`.  I want these triples to be sorted by the `"data1"` field and mapped. In this case,

```
"key1" =>  {[1, "data5", "data6"] [3, "data8", "data9"] [4, "data2", "data3"]}
```

How do I do this Ruby?

Comment: This is not valid syntax - `"key1" =>  [1 "data5"  "data6"] [3 "data8"  "data9"] [4 "data2"  "data3"]`. Give the proper firmat first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below :

```
hsh = {"key1" => [[4,"data2","data3"], [1, "data5","data6"],[3, "data8","data9"]] }
hsh.each{|k,v| hsh[k]=v.sort_by(&:first)}
p hsh
# >> {"key1"=>[[1, "data5", "data6"], [3, "data8", "data9"], [4, "data2", "data3"]]}
```

If you don't want to update the source hash,then use `#dup`.

```
hsh = {"key1" => [[4,"data2","data3"], [1, "data5","data6"],[3, "data8","data9"]] }
hsh1 = hsh.dup
hsh1.each{|k,v| hsh1[k]=v.sort_by(&:first)}
p hsh1
# >> {"key1"=>[[1, "data5", "data6"], [3, "data8", "data9"], [4, "data2", "data3"]]}
```